# Measure theory - image measure question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f:E\to G$ is a measurable function between two measurable spaces and $\mu$ is a measure on $E$, I am considering the image measure $\nu = \mu \circ f^{-1}$. I want to show that $\nu(g) = \mu(g \circ f)$ for all non-negative measurable functions $g$ on $G$. Please could you help me to do this - I am a beginner in the measure theory.

Comment: What do you mean by $\nu(g)$ and $\mu(g \circ f)$? Is this supposed to be the integral? If it is, the idea of the proof is to first show it for simple functions and then use the fact that you can approximate every measurable function by simple functions.

Answer (score 1):

What we have to show is that 
$$\int_G  g\mathrm d\nu=\int_E g\circ f\mathrm d\mu$$
for each $g$ non-negative. As suggested by [Lukas Geyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43179/lukas-geyer), we can first show it when $g$ is the characteristic function of a measurable subset of $G$. So far, so good, since this is the definition of the image measure.

Then we use linearity of the integral in order to extend it to linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable subsets of $G$.

Then recall that $\int_G g\mathrm d\nu=\sup\left\{\int_G s\mathrm d\nu,0\leqslant s\leqslant g, s\mbox{ simple}\right\}$.